Android: intercept back navigation with a gesture in Jetpack Compose
I want to intercept back navigation gestures in my Android app. Found this as a suggestion, but it doesn't get invoked, no matter where I place it in the Composables hierarchy:
BackHandler(enabled = true) {
    Log.d("BackHandler", "back")
}

Is there a way to intercept back gesture in Compose?

Did you see this?

Could you please try expanding more on where are you calling this? I faced a similar issue when invoking the back handler from a view inside a NavHost later I found that the NavHost override the behavior of the BackHandler.
